# OnKeyUp does not fire after the OnKeyPress event is intercepted in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

It looks like `OnKeyUp` does not fire after the `OnKeyPress` event is intercepted in windows forms. I would like to be able to intercept both events. Is that possible?

```
private void OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  // do something innocuous
}

private void OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  // do something innocuous
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible with the right implementation. Please share the code in the `OnKeyUp` and `OnKeyPress` methods.

Comment: are you sure you are not using e.Handled = true?

Comment: I am certainly not using e.Handled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property of the Form to `true`.

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress,
>   KeyDown, and KeyUp events.

You can set it in the designer or in code.

```
public Form1()
{       
   this.KeyPreview = true;
}
```